# Why aren't my strings printing the proper value?

Tags: c

Here is my code to print the string

```
char accname[MAX][MAXSTRING], transname[MAX][MAXSTRING];

printf ("Enter title for new account: ");
accname[i][i] = validatestring();
printf ("\n");

printf ("Enter title for transaction: ");
transname[i][i] = validatestring();
printf ("\n");

printf ("%s  %s", accname[i], transname[i]);
```

my code for validatestring()

```
char validatestring() {
    int keeptrying = 1, rc;
    char i[31];
    do
    {
        rc = scanf("%30[^\n]", &i);
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            clear();
        }
        else if (getchar() != '\n')
        {
            printf (" **Title is longer than 30 characters: ");
            clear();
        }
        else
        {
            keeptrying = 0;
        }
    } while (keeptrying == 1);
    return i;
}
```

at the printf stage for accname[i] / transname[i] i don't get the value I entered, I get weird conversion string types, sometimes I got the first character of my input but now I get something completely different. Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: Compile with warnings and fix them.

Comment: Your code is invalid C. It is formally non-compilable. Any self-respecting compiler will issue a large number of diagnostic messages for this code. Until you fix them, there's no point in analyzing the behavior of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validatestring` function is hopelesely broken.

Firstly, you declared `validatestring` as returning `char`. Yet you attempt too return a `char *` from it (see `return i`, where `i` is `char [31]`). This should not even compile.

Secondly, if you intend to return a string from `validatestring`, you have to make sure that  you are not returning a pointer to a local buffer from it. `i` is a local array. A pointer to `i` cannot be returned from `validatestring`.

Comment: Could you give some tips on how to fix it / what im doing wrong?

Comment: It may compile because `i` will decay to pointer type and the function returns an integer type. It's atrocious, but GCC will still compile it, with a warning about returning an integer from a pointer without casting.

Comment: Ahh very nice, I instead just called the function validatestring() and put the array from main into that and it worked!

Comment: @netcoder: Even GCC should complain about returning a pointer where a char was expected, though.  If any compiler doesn't, then *it* is hopelessly broken as well.

Comment: @cHao: I just said that it complains heh. But it compiles it though.

Comment: @netcoder: Eh.  I sometimes forget that warnings aren't errors by default.  :P

Comment: @cHao: Well the standard says that it's valid C too (C99 6.3.2.3/6). It doesn't expressly forbid implicit conversion in those cases either. However, it clearly states that the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: @netcoder: No, the standard doesn't say it's valid. The standard forbids implicit conversions from pointers to integers and vice versa. The standard explicitly requires the types involved into assignment, initialization, `return` etc. to be *compatible*. There's no context in C language in which the conversion described in 6.3.2.3/6 would be allowed as an *implicit* conversion. For this reason 6.3.2.3/6 is only possible with an explicit cast. If you want GCC to generate errors for what the standard considers a constraint violation, you have to run it with `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that is because what you are doing is trying to store everything in one char.

```
array[i][i]
```

which is a character position in which you are trying to store everything in it

I think what you intend to do is

```
*array[i]  // It is a pointer to that location which you referring to.
```

This will store your string in array[i] from which you can access your characters using

```
 array[i][i]
```

I hope this solves your problem.Also your function should return a char pointer char*.

This should do it:

```
   *accname[i] = validatestring();
```

Also change the return type of your function to char*

Comment: Could you be more clear? You just used the same array[i] / array[i][i] to explain everything and it looks confusing

Comment: Hmm...well it's kinda working because the printing value is now the first character of what is supposed to be a string, but i guess it's only returning the first character? I made the changes you said as well

Comment: @Fyre: I'm pretty sure C doesn't just let you copy arrays around like that (`*accname[i] = pretty_much_anything;`).  There should be a `memcpy` or `strncpy` somewhere in there.  :P  Unless you pass in a pointer to a buffer, anyway.  Actually, *assuming* you pass a buffer -- otherwise, the instant you return, `i` becomes invalid, so you'd have to copy the chars out before that.